# Disable prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication for devise passwordcontroller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im trying to override and remove the

:require_no_authentication in devise's password controller.

```
class Devise::PasswordsController < DeviseController

  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication
```

With:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
```

However this does not work, reason for this is I want to use the edit method from the password controller to have custom logic. I want to update the users password when they are logged in.

Is there a correct way to disable this prepend_before_filter somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems with this for a few days now. This post solve them and I hope it'll help you too..
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2811

Basically we need to override the authenticate_your_model! method, because there is a check that disables authentication for every devise controller. So just remove the skip_before_filter and add a private method like this:

```
private

def authenticate_your_model!(opts={})
  opts[:scope] = :system_manager
  warden.authenticate!(opts) # if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
end
```